# Is it possible to get the id to be inserted in the database before insert

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm using PDO with PostgreSQL in PHP.

I'll let my users uploads files.

I would like to add the record id to the saved image.

Is it possible to get (or reserve) the record id before insertion in the database.

I don't think this is possible just want to be sure.

Comment: I don't know PostgreSQL but maybe you can get the last id that was inserted. adding 1 to it would probably give you the id to be inserted assuming your id is primary key with identity property.

Comment: What if the last record was deleted? That would definitively get the wrong id.

Comment: @nevayeshirazi That's a bad idea. What happens if another session adds a row, or gets the same id using that mechanism?

Comment: Although it is not efficient at all,maybe table level lock can be used until the user is done with insert operation to block other users from inserting or deleting entities from table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is, you should use postgres function `nextval` to fetch the next value in the sequence. Look the default value in your table's id column, it should contain a nextval call to the used sequence.

For example if the table looks something like this:

```
image_id bigint not null default nextval('image_image_id_seq'::regclass)
data bytea not null
```

You can call:

```
SELECT NEXTVAL('image_image_id_seq') ;
```

which will "reserve" the id for you to be used later on:

```
INSERT INTO image (image_id, data) VALUES (?, ?) ;
```

Comment: Is `nextval` per connection. Or can it be that I get the nextval and somelse inserts a record in the database with that id?

Comment: It's a global sequence, when you pick a value from the sequence is increased by one and that value won't be used again.

Comment: Great! Does MySQL also has something with this functionality?

Comment: I don't think it's possible in MySQL.

Comment: @PeerHaa: no that is not possible with MySQL because it does not support sequences.

Comment: @PeeHaa: [`nextval`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) is global but `currval` and `lastval` are per-session.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this :

```
BEGIN
INSERT RETURNING
get id
rename file
COMMIT
```